# Android M write external storage acces denied to create file

Tags: android

Failed to create file after ask permission

MainActivity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},200);

...

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    else if(requestCode==200 && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        try {
            Utils.createFile(list);
...
```

Utils.class

```
public static void createFile(List<NetworkObj> list) throws IOException {
    Log.wtf("lolol", Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "wifi_pass.txt");
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"wifi_pass.txt");
    if(file.exists()) file.delete();
    if(file.createNewFile() && file.exists()){
```

Log

`java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
at ua.sytor.wifipass.Utils.createFile(Utils.java:106)`

Also i had included to manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: Does the `Downloads/` directory exist?

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry. It seems that problem caused by my device. After reboot everything works